# Как оформить код в Word для курсача?

Tags: c

Как можно красиво оформить исходный код на языке си для курсовой работы в ворде, которую потом буду печатать?

Comment: Напишите кто-то, что то типа:

Просто нужно код из Visual Studio скопировать в MS Word, подсветка кода будет автоматическая.

Выберу правильным ответом.

Comment: >Напишите кто-то, что то типа:
Просто нужно код из Visual Studio скопировать в MS Word, подсветка кода будет автоматическая.
Выберу правильным ответом

если у вас есть, как вы считаете, верный ответ (и вопрос, очевидно, уже не актуален), то зачем вам нужно, чтобы кто-то здесь формально отписался? Вы, извините за выражение, занимаетесь кармадрочерством и выпрашиваете ответ, чтобы принять его и получить два очка кармы? В любом случае у вас есть ответ @KoVadim, можете принять его

Comment: Просто это самый рабочий способ. Ответ пользователя @KoVadim не всегда срабатывает и трубет лишних движений. Я заинтересован в том, что бы люди видели удобные способы, видимо Вы иного мнения. Ваше право.

Comment: Последний раз, когда я пробовал вставлять код с студии в ворд, никакой подсветки автоматом не было. Возможно, это последние версии такое умеют.

Comment: Набрел на этот вопрос из любопытства, не будут ли говорить, что код «для раздувания курсовой». Я решил проблему форматирования так — я пишу курсовую на Markdown + CSS. Это позволяет с одной стороны получше выучить CSS, с другой стороны без проблем писать курсовую в Emacs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь любым сервисом подсветки синтаксиса. Например, первое, что попало в поиске - http://hilite.me/ . Подсвеченный текст можно скопировать и вставить в ворд. Вот [ещё](http://www.planetb.ca/2008/11/syntax-highlight-code-in-word-documents/) один сервис.

А ещё есть плагин для ворда - ADX Toys 2 WD (легко гуглиться).

Answer (score 6):

Обычно достаточно вставить текст как есть, выбрать моноширинный шрифт (Courier New или Consolas например) и убрать междустрочный интервал. На подсветку преподам пофиг.